# How to inherit width of min-width and max-width?

Tags: css

How to inherit the `width` of the parent with `min-width` and/or `max-width`?

The child element `#main_header` must have the same width as the parent element `#main`

I have added `#main_inner` as an intermediate/helper element.

## jsfiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/p010bx5w/4/

```css
#main {
position:relative;
min-width:200px;
max-width:300px;
  background:blue;
  height:350px;
}

#main_inner {
width:100%;
background:red;
height:300px;
}

#main_header {
position:fixed;
width:inherit;
  background:yellow
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main_inner">
<div id="main_header">
  hey
  <div style="text-align:right">right</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer to the title "How to inherit width of min-width and max-width?" is:

```
min-width: inherit;
max-width: inherit;
```

Since there is also a helper container in the middle, you'll have to set it on that as well, and add `width: 100%;` to the child, it seems to be working well.

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#main_inner {
  min-width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

#main_header {
  min-width: inherit;
  max-width: inherit;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div id="main_inner">
    <div id="main_header">hey</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Added a jQuery approach below:

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $('#main_header').css('width', $('#main').width());
}).trigger('resize');
```

```js
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  $('#main_header').css('width', $('#main').width());
}).trigger('resize');
```

```css
#main {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
  max-width: 300px;
  background: red;
}

#main_inner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: yellow;
}

#main_header {
  position: fixed;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="main_inner">
    <div id="main_header">
      hey
      <div style="text-align:right">right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I always thought `inherit` was the default, but I guess not in this case, or maybe not for the property `max-width`, because this fixed my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you're assuming min-width and max-width rules automatically effect Width for child elements itself.
Simply set the min-width rules to inherit and you're good to go

```
#main_header {
  position:fixed;
  min-width:inherit;
  background:blue
}
```

In response to your edit:
Having a child element that is exactly the same width as its parent is as simple as setting the child to 100% width

```
#main_header {
  position:fixed;
  min-width:inherit;
  max-width:inherit;
  width:100%;
  background:blue
}
```